# Windows Phone Sliding Page/Control

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I want to design a page on windows phone 8.1 which should have 2 pages in a screen.

One page should always be visible.

Second page should come up when user tries to "hold and tries to swap to right on the left corner of the visible screen"

[The Second Page i'm planning to make it as a User control. so that i can put it on different pages as a hidden control and will show up when user tries hold and drag from left to right, action on a page just the way action center shows in phone]

It's same way how action center page comes up when user hold's and drag down the top corner of phone screen windows phone 8.1, but I'm trying to do the same but from the dragging should be from left side of the Screen.

I have tried experimenting with Manipulation methods could achieve the expected result.

Hope i have conveyed my question properly. :)

Please share your thought's.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but is [That](https://sparecode.wordpress.com/2015/03/05/navigation-drawer-wp-winr/) what you are looking for ?

Application side menu (NavigationDrawer) ?

Comment: Yes I'm looking for similar solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [this](https://slideview.codeplex.com) project, see if it suit your need. You need some changes in source to make it work with Windows 8.1